# How to fire an textchange event of autocomplete jquery ajax function when manualy a value is entered or selected from the list?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-autocomplete, textchanged

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Origin(sender, args) {

    $(function () {
        $("#<%=Info.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Webservice.asmx/Get") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    mustMatch: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {

                    },
                    failure: function (response) {

                    }
                });
            },

            select: function (e, i) {

                $("#<%=hdnShipperInfo.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);

                if (i.item.val == "No Records Found") {
                    $("#<%=hdnInfo.ClientID %>").val(-1);
                    document.getElementById('<%=Info.ClientID%>').value = "";
                    return false;
                }

            },
            minLength: 0

        }).bind('focus', function () { $(this).autocomplete("search"); });
        $(".selector").autocomplete({
            change: function (event, ui) { info(); }
        });
    });

    }


 </script>
```